# I try to use computed to watch navigator.onLine but not work until I refresh the web?

Tags: html, vue.js, vuejs2, navigator

I try to use  computed to watch navigator.onLine but not work until I refresh the web?

```
<template><div>{{isOnline}}</div></template>
...
<scirpt>
...
  computed: {
    isOnline() {
      return navigator.onLine;
    },
  },
...
</script>
```

Comment: where is your navigator? Is it in data option or what?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Browsers api are not reactive**. So whenever their value changes, Vue doesn't know about it.

To listen to `navigator.onLine` changes, you have to use a native event fired by the browser (see [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/onLine#listening_for_changes_in_network_status)):

```js
data () {
  return {
    online: false,
  }
},
methods: {
  onOffline () { this.online = false },
  onOnline () { this.online = true },
  created() {
    window.addEventListener('offline', this.onOffline)
    window.addEventListener('online', this.onOnline)
  },
  destroyed() {
    window.removeEventListener('offline', this.onOffline)
    window.removeEventListener('online', this.onOnline)
  }
}
```

---

Note: be careful with SSR, `window` doesn't exist on server.

Comment: Yeah right, the previous syntax was not working with `this`. Thanks for the edit.

Answer (score 1):

Like @Kaocash said browsers api are not reactive, so a watcher won't work

Original answer :

---

Well, computed property will be updated when data changes on your component,
what you need is a watcher :

```html
<template><div>{{isOnline}}</div></template>
...
<script>
...
  data() {
      return {
          isOnline: true
      }
  },
  watch: {
    'navigator.onLine'(val) {
      this.isOnline = val
    },
  },
...
</script>
```